# How to load a URL in my single page JavaScript app using Browser history state?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I am wanting to use History state in my JavaScript app.

This JSFiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/xyft1pfa/ changes the URL to these values when the links are clicked on:

- /page-1/
- /page-2/
- /page-3/

My question is how would I go about making these URL's load content from my app if I accessed these URLs directly in the browser?

Currently if I do so, it obviously tries to find that page/endpoint on the server to load which does not exist.

Clicking the link to load Page 3 will update the URL to `/page-3/` but then if I was to manually load `/page-3/` into the address bar it would load a 404 missing page as the file doesn't exist.   I am wanting to figure out a way to make it load my single page JS app and load the right content on that page when that URL is accessed in any manner.

I am not using a framework.

```
// this should be the Ajax Method.
// and load the url content
var setCurrentPage = function(url) {
  $('h2 span').html(url || "/");
  $("#menu-nav a[href='" + url + "']").fadeTo(500, 0.3);
};

$('#menu-nav a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var targetUrl = $(this).attr('href'),
    targetTitle = $(this).attr('title');

  $("#menu-nav a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").fadeTo(500, 1.0);

  window.history.pushState({
    url: "" + targetUrl + ""
  }, targetTitle, targetUrl);
  setCurrentPage(targetUrl);
});

window.onpopstate = function(e) {
  $("#menu-nav a").fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
  setCurrentPage(e.state ? e.state.url : null);
};
```

HTML

```
<h2>Current Page: <span>/</span></h2>
<ul id="menu-nav">
  <li><a href="/page-1/" title="Pagina 1">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/page-2/" title="Pagina 2">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/page-3/" title="Pagina 3">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In setCurrentPage load the page data from the server by an ajax request:

```
var serverBase = "http://example.com/getPage?page=";
var setCurrentPage = function(url) {
  $.getJSON(serverBase + url, function(json){
    $('h2 span').html(json.html);
    $("#menu-nav a[href='" + url + "']").fadeTo(500, 0.3);
  });
};
```

And server could respond via a json:

```
{"html": "<div>got from the server</div>"}
```

You'll need to set the correct url according to what you expect in the server.

You might also get some ideas about how to use the #hash of the location for single-page websites: You might also have a look at this idea: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling

Comment: Hi than ks I am not asking about loading AJAX content.  What I need help with is making my app load the single page app whenever these URLs are accessed int he browser instead of  them trying to load new files.  SO in your example instead of the server loading domain.com/page1/index.html`  it would load `http://example.com/getPage?page=page1` when I access `domain.com/page1` in the browser

Comment: One of us doesn't understand the other, but I don't know yet who :) If you put my code to domain.com, then you'll seemingly browse pages on domain.com, while the actual data would come from example.com.